# Difference between task and request in Oracle Coherence

Tags: oracle, caching, oracle-coherence

In Oracle Coherence there are two service metrics exposed via JMX/reporting (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHMG/analyze_report.htm#COHMG250):

`Request Count` - The number of requests since the last report refresh execution

`Task Count` - The number of tasks executed since the last report refresh

What is the difference between a `request` and a `task`?

Answer (score 0):

A **request** is call to Service (for example PartitionedCache) for get/set cache operation.

**Task** is work execution (mostly internal to Coherence in order to fetch/set data or processing data), which is associated with Cache Service. See details on task (see PriorityTask):

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHJR/toc.htm